# Django App Deployed in Azure not Displayed

Tags: python, django, azure, deployment, wsgi

We have a Django app which runs perfectly in our local environment and also is deployed in Heroku (run smoothly there too).
However, when deployed in Azure we see this image from the Azure portal:
[image]

The wsgi file looks like this:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'django_gui.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Referencing all the files in the settings.py which are all set up accordingly to the django checklist in manage.py check --deploy

In Azure we have tried various ways of deploying it, from Azure Devops Repos, to pushing the file from Azure CLI. Any hint or input would be highly appreciated.